# Multiple Select - inserting data into MySQL DB Many to Many relation (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry if this is not well explained, I am still fairly new.

My issue is - I need to insert multiple select data into a movie Database.

My relational database looks like this:

[image]

This is my current PHP code,

```
<?php
require "settings/init.php";

if (!empty($_POST["data"])) {
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $file = $_FILES;

    if (!empty($file["movImg"]["tmp_name"])){
        move_uploaded_file($file["movImg"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . basename($file["movImg"]["name"]));
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO movie (movName, movDesc, movRelDate, movRating, movActors, movProducers, movType, movReview, movImg) VALUES (:movName, :movDesc, :movRelDate, :movRating, :movActors, :movProducers, :movType, :movReview, :movImg)";
    $bind = [
        ":movName" => $data["movName"],
        ":movDesc" => $data["movDesc"],
        ":movRelDate" => $data["movRelDate"],
        ":movRating" => $data["movRating"],
        ":movActors" => $data["movActors"],
        ":movProducers" => $data["movProducers"],
        ":movType" => $data["movType"],
        ":movReview" => $data["movReview"],
        ":movImg" => (!empty($file["movImg"]["tmp_name"])) ? $file["movImg"]["name"] : NULL,
    ];

    $db->sql($sql, $bind, false);

    echo include 'includes/success.php';
    exit;
}
?>
```

This will correctly grab data from input fields such as

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="movName">Title*</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="data[movName]" id="movName" placeholder="Title" value="" required>
</div>
```

Now I need to somehow do the same for my multiple select values and insert the "movId" and the "genId" into my genreconmovie table, both the PHP and the SQL statements is a puzzle to me, this is what I have so far for my multiple select object:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="genre">Categories*</label>
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon fas fa-theater-masks"></i>
                <select class="selectpicker" name="data[genId]" type="number" id="genId"
                        placeholder="Choose categories..." required multiple aria-label="Categories">
                    <option value="1">Action</option>
                    <option value="2">Comedy</option>
                    <option value="3">Drama</option>
                    <option value="4">Fantasy</option>
                    <option value="5">Horror</option>
                    <option value="6">Mystery</option>
                    <option value="7">Romance</option>
                    <option value="8">Sci-Fi</option>
                    <option value="9">Thriller</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what I need to do is insert the current movie id (movId) + genre id (genId) into my genreconmovie table, is anyone able to help? And please let me know if you want the files I have, or my SQL export from PHPMYADMIN or similar, I'll supply anything if it helps.

In advance thanks for looking at my post, and hope someone can help!

Comment: So you will get the `last_insert_id` after your query execution and genre id from post data. After running a separate query to insert data into the `genreconmovie` table.

Comment: @MainulHasan could u explain how you would write that out? :S

Comment: After inserting data get id using `$last_id = $con->insert_id;` `genre id = data["genId"]` then write your query

Comment: @MainulHasan I cant quite get it to work, so 

`$last_id = $con->insert_id;    $genre_id = $data["genId"];    $sql = "INSERT INTO genreconmovie (movId, genId) VALUES (:movId, :genId)";    $bind = [":movId" => $last_id,  ":genId" => $genre_id, ];`

This is what I made so far

If you could expand your explanation a bit, and kinda give specific examples I would be very grateful :/ I'll keep trying

Comment: It's not working, `$con` is your connection variable? Make sure its correct seems all are fine, finally execute your new SQL

Comment: Gives me an error message of "Error message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'movId' cannot be null" - and Google is not being very helpful with this error

I believe this `$dbCon` is my connection variable from my init.php file (if I understand the code correctly)

Comment: `var_dump($last_id)` seems it's empty. Make sure, your previous query is executed properly or you can run another query `SELECT movId FROM movie ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`  to get newly inserted movId

Comment: @MainulHasan is there any way to get into a chat or something, I need more extensive help with this, I have been on this for literally 10 hours this same issue, and I cannot figure it out, not even with the help you tried to provide here :/

Comment: How will I contact you?

Comment: @MainulHasan Do you have Skype or Discord?

Comment: moh.mainul.hasan@gmail.com email me.